# How to audit who ran query on abcd database im Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Have abcd database. one user has executed query on abcd database. Another user has executed another query on abcd database. Like this whenever different user has executed different user has executed query on abcd database. Need to capture user execution time and who has executed query..etc

Answer (score 0):

This information is gathered from https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/access-history.html which is basically the access history details. Also, the same detail can be checked from Snowflake - Query History - Filters where you can use username or any other parameter to look up the details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Query_history view available in Snowflake.ACCOUNT_USAGE schema to get the complete information of the query within the last 365 days including user_name, execution time, etc

Please note Latency for the view may be up to 45 minutes.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/query_history.html#query-history-view

Also, you can use QUERY_HISTORY function available in information_schema  to retrieve query information within the last 7 days and with no latency.

Please review the below documentation for more information.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/query_history.html#query-history-query-history-by

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage.html#differences-between-account-usage-and-information-schema

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query(you can add the columns as you need):

```html
     select distinct QH.query_id, QH.USER_NAME,qh.database_name,Qh.start_time, qh.EXECUTION_TIME from 
 "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."QUERY_HISTORY" QH
   where  
  -- QH.query_id='' --If you know the query id,use it here
  -- QH.user_name='USERNAME' -- You can filter by user id
  QH.database_name='DBNAME' --you can filter by databasename
  and qh.start_time > '2022-06-29 12:45:36.291'-- you can filter by date
;
```

If you want to track the IP address and application from where query was run, you can use below query as well:

```html
select distinct QH.query_id,LH.client_ip, QH.USER_NAME,s.client_application_id,qh.database_name,Qh.start_time, qh.EXECUTION_TIME from snowflake.account_usage.login_history LH 
inner join "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."QUERY_HISTORY" QH
on QH.USER_NAME=LH.user_name 
inner join  "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."SESSIONS" S on S.session_id=QH.session_id 
and s.LOGIN_EVENT_ID=lh.EVENT_ID
   where  
  -- QH.query_id='' --If you know the query id,use it here
  -- QH.user_name='USERNAME' --If you know the user id,use it here
  QH.database_name='DBNAME' --If you know the DB id,use it here
  and qh.start_time > '2022-06-29 12:45:36.291'-- filter by date as required
  ;
```